# How do i convert an image read with cv2.imread('img.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) to the format of cv2.imread('img.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to read an image in unchanged format, do some operations and convert it back to the colored format

```
im = cv2.imread(fname,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # shape(240,240,4)
....
im2 = cv2.imread(im,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # required shape(240,240,3)
```

But, looks like I can't input the result of first numpy array into the second imread.
So currently I've created a temporary image after the operations and reading that value to get the required im2 value.

```
im = cv2.imread(fname,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # shape(240,240,4)
....
cv2.imwrite('img.png',im)
im2 = cv2.imread('img.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # required shape(240,240,3)
```

However I would like to avoid the step of creating temporary image. How would I achieve the same with a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has a function for color conversion `cvtColor`

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

```
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im, <conversion code>)
```

You should figure out conversion code yourself, based on image format you have. Probably, it would be `cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR`